# Attempting to mound my directory in docker (to run pyspark)

Tags: python, docker, pyspark, bigdata

I have a directory which I am trying to mount in docker to use a pyspark container.

I am passing the following code to try and host my local directory in the container

`docker run -it -p 8888:8888 -v {absolute file path}:/home/jovyan/work --rm jupyter/pyspark-notebook`

Users/{myname}/Documents/{filepath}" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path.

Any ideas on whats going wrong and next steps would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you _sure_ it’s an absolute path — does it have a `/` at the very beginning?

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your reply. It does not have a / at the very beginning, and starts with 'Users'

Comment: User home directories on MacOS are in `/Users` with a leading slash at the front.  That leading slash is important to Docker; try adding it in.

Comment: Thanks David, i think this has worked (in theory) but flagged another problem, 'Bind for 0.0.0.0:8888 failed: port is already allocated.' is this because i currently have an instance running?

Comment: Bind failed - yes, maybe something is holding on to port 8888. What do you get with `docker ps -a` ?  (Aso, whatever is on port 8888 might not be a Docker container either.)

Comment: Hi David. I've got it all working now. Thank you very much for all your help